# Dynamic Data UIHint("MultilineText_Edit") in Grid and Edit

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

When a particular property on my model is attributed with UIHint("MultilineText_Edit") it renders the multiline text edit in the Details view, but not in the Edit view. In the Edit view it's a tiny little textbox. Any idea how to persuage DD to render that as a multiline in the Edit view as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely its looking for MultilineText_Edit_Edit.ascx. As the convention is to look for the one with _Edit at the end.

Try if it works in edit when u have a copy of the user control named like that.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I made a copy like you said, called the file "MultilineText_Edit_Edit.ascx" but I had to change the class name. I just tacked a '1' on the end.

Comment: Answer my same question and win some points.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501152/uihint-not-working-for-edit

Thanks!

Comment: @ProfK I just voted close as dup on that one, any upvote from anyone that follows it here are enough.